# Fix the Laravel concurrency problem. Between if condition and insert eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, concurrency, innodb

**PHP** version: **7.2.4**

**Laravel** version: **5.8.34**

MySQL version: **5.6.41**

MySQL server type: **MySQL**

MySQL tables storage engine: **InnoDB**

**Description:**

There is concurrency in these codes:

```
...

$orderExist = Order::where('address', $address)
    ->where('order_status', 'open')
    ->where('type', 'bulk')
    ->where('way', 'site')
    ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon:today())
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->exists();

if (!$orderExist) {
    $order = Order::create([
        'admin_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'address'  => $address,
        'status'   => 'open',
        'type'     => 'bulk',
        'way'      => 'site',
    ]);
} else {
    return 'duplicate_order';
}

OrderProduct::create([
    'order_id'   => $order->id,
    'product_id' => $product->id,
    'count'      => $request->count,
    'unit_id'    => $product->unit_id,
    'brand_id'   => $product->brand_id,
]);

...
```

The code tell us: If there is the special order in `orders` table, return back. But if there is no the special order , create a new order and after that insert new product for this new order.

But sometimes two requests insert two duplicate order concurrently in `orders` table.

I've found these ways:

1. Laravel queue: It doesn't return the new inserted order id and also it can't resolve concurrency problem.
2. Laravel transaction: It's not possible to use `if` condition in that. Also it is about rollback multiple query if some of them queries are failed and isn't about resolve concurrency problem
3. `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query: It query causes run both of requests. Therefore it isn't correct about concurrency issue.
4. Lock table: The InnoDB storage engine supports only **row-level locking** and doesn't support **table-level locking**. Base on [MyISAM-concurrent-inserts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/concurrent-inserts.html) and [innodb-locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html).
5. ...

Please help me resolve this concurrency issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `GET_LOCK()` and `RELEASE_LOCK()`.